# Navigating to another route - rerouting back to loginView

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Problem: After successful login I want to navigate to "home" view. Unfortunately it only blinks and goes back to LoginView.

I am using vaadin session to store logged in user data like that:

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute(UserModel::class.java, result.second!!)
```

Setting HomeView route as accessible for current session:

```
RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope().setRoute(AdminPanelRoute.HOME, HomeView::class.java)
```

Navigating to home view:

```
ui.get().navigate(HomeView::class.java)
```

LoginView.kt content:

```
import com.fd.jvmbackend.data.model.UserModel
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.AdminPanelRoute
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.BaseView
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.home.HomeView
import com.vaadin.flow.component.AttachEvent
import com.vaadin.flow.component.DetachEvent
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Unit
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextFieldVariant
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route
import com.vaadin.flow.router.RouteConfiguration
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession


@Route(value = AdminPanelRoute.LOGIN)
@PageTitle("Login | FD CMS")
class LoginView() : BaseView(false) {

    private val TAG = "LoginView"

    private var viewModel: LoginViewModel? = null


    override fun onAttach(attachEvent: AttachEvent?) {
        super.onAttach(attachEvent)

        viewModel = LoginViewModel()

        val label = Label("Welcome.")

        val loginField = getLoginTextField("Login", "ex: mike", true, true)
        loginField.addThemeVariants(TextFieldVariant.MATERIAL_ALWAYS_FLOAT_LABEL)
        loginField.value = "admin"

        val passwordField = getPasswordField("Password", "ex. myLongPassword", true, true, true)
        passwordField.value = "pass"
        passwordField.addThemeVariants(TextFieldVariant.MATERIAL_ALWAYS_FLOAT_LABEL)

        val button = Button("Log in with credentials")
        button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY)
        button.setWidth(15F, Unit.PERCENTAGE)

        button.addClickListener { event ->

            ui.get().access {
                VaadinSession.getCurrent().session.invalidate()
                VaadinSession.getCurrent().close()
                RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope().removeRoute(AdminPanelRoute.HOME)
            }

            viewModel?.onLoginClicked(loginField.value, passwordField.value) { result ->

                println("$TAG -> [onLoginClicked] result -> ${result.first} / ${result.second}")
                if (result.first) {
                        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute(UserModel::class.java, result.second!!)
                        println("$TAG -> [onLoginClicked] getAttribute -> ${VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute(UserModel::class.java)} / state -> ${VaadinSession.getCurrent().state.name}")
                        RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope().setRoute(AdminPanelRoute.HOME, HomeView::class.java)
                        ui.get().navigate(HomeView::class.java)
                }
            }
        }


        add(label)
        add(loginField)
        add(passwordField)

        add(button)
        
    }

    override fun onDetach(detachEvent: DetachEvent?) {
        viewModel?.onCleared()
        viewModel = null
        super.onDetach(detachEvent)
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.kt:

```
import com.fd.jvmbackend.data.model.UserModel
import com.fd.jvmbackend.extensions.isNotNull
import com.fd.jvmbackend.repository.UserRepository
import com.fd.jvmbackend.service.AdminAuthorizationService
import com.fd.jvmbackend.util.AppInfo
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.ViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext


class LoginViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private val TAG = "LoginViewModel"

    private val userRepository: UserRepository by lazy {
        UserRepository(AppInfo.production)
    }

    private val adminAuthorizationService: AdminAuthorizationService by lazy {
        AdminAuthorizationService(AppInfo.production)
    }


    init {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            setPageTitle("Login")
        }

    }


    fun onLoginClicked(login: String?, password: String?, result: (Pair<Boolean, UserModel?>) -> Unit) {
        println("$TAG -> onLoginClicked / login _> ${login} / password _> ${password}")

        setIsLoading(true)
        setErrorText(null)

        val inputValuesErrorText = inputValuesErrorText(login, password)
        println("$TAG -> onLoginClicked / inputValuesErrorText _> ${inputValuesErrorText} / isEmpty _> ${inputValuesErrorText.isEmpty()}")

        val authorized = adminAuthorizationService.isAuthorized(login!!, password!!)

        val resultError = if (inputValuesErrorText.isNotNull()) {
            inputValuesErrorText
        } else {
            if (authorized) null else "Wrong credentials!"
        }

        setErrorText(resultError)
        setIsLoading(false)

        result.invoke(Pair(authorized, if (authorized) userRepository.getUserByUsername(login) else null))

    }


    private fun inputValuesErrorText(login: String?, password: String?): String {
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        if (login?.length == 0) {
            stringBuilder.appendLine("Login is empty.")
        }
        if (password?.length == 0) {
            stringBuilder.appendLine("Password is empty.")
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString()
    }

}
```

HomeView.kt:

```
import com.fd.jvmbackend.data.model.UserModel
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.BaseView
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.login.LoginView
import com.vaadin.flow.component.AttachEvent
import com.vaadin.flow.component.DetachEvent
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession


//@Route(value = AdminPanelRoute.HOME)
@PageTitle("Home | FD CMS")
class HomeView() : BaseView(true) {

    private val TAG = "HomeView"


    private val loggedInUser:UserModel? by lazy {
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute(UserModel::class.java) as? UserModel
    }

    override fun onAttach(attachEvent: AttachEvent?) {
        super.onAttach(attachEvent)
//        setId("login-view")
//       if(loggedInUser == null){
//           clearSession()
//       }

        val label = Label("HOME.")


        add(label)

    }

    override fun onDetach(detachEvent: DetachEvent?) {
        super.onDetach(detachEvent)
    }

    private fun clearSession(){
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().session.invalidate()
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().close()
        ui.get().navigate(LoginView::class.java)
    }

}
```

Spring security configuration:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter


@EnableWebSecurity
open class SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()

             // Allow all Vaadin internal requests.
            .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
    }


    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity?) {
        super.configure(web)
        web?.ignoring()?.antMatchers(
            // Client-side JS
            "/VAADIN/**",

            // the standard favicon URI
            "/favicon.ico",

            // the robots exclusion standard
            "/robots.txt",

            // web application manifest
            "/manifest.webmanifest",
            "/sw.js",
            "/offline.html",

            // icons and images
            "/icons/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/styles/**",

            // (development mode) H2 debugging console
            "/h2-console/**");
    }
}
```

App.kt:

```
import com.rfksystems.blake2b.security.Blake2bProvider
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
import java.security.Security


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [SecurityAutoConfiguration::class, JacksonAutoConfiguration::class, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration::class])

open class App {

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            Security.addProvider(Blake2bProvider())

            SpringApplication.run(App::class.java, *args)

        }
    }
}
```

AppShellConfigurator:

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.AppShellConfigurator
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push
import com.vaadin.flow.shared.communication.PushMode
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.lumo.Lumo

@Theme(themeClass = Lumo::class, variant = Lumo.DARK)
@Push(PushMode.AUTOMATIC)
class AppShell : AppShellConfigurator
```

AdminAuthorizationService.kt:

```
import com.fd.jvmbackend.data.constants.UserRole
import com.fd.jvmbackend.data.constants.UserState
import com.fd.jvmbackend.service.exception.UserNotFoundException
import com.fd.jvmbackend.util.base.validation.Argon2PasswordHash
import com.fd.jvmbackend.util.generator.HashTextGenerator
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession


class AdminAuthorizationService(private val productionMode: Boolean) : BaseService(productionMode) {

    private val TAG = "AdminAuthorizationService"

    private val emailService: EmailService by lazy {
        EmailService(productionMode)
    }

    fun isAuthorized(username: String, password: String): Boolean {

        createDefaultAdminUserIfNotExists()
        println("$TAG -> [validateCredentials]  !!!!!!!!")
        val valid = validateCredentials(username, password)
        if (valid) {

        }

        if (!productionMode) {
            println("$TAG -> [isAuthorized] / valid -> $valid")
        }

        return valid
    }

    fun logout() {
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().session.invalidate()
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().close()
    }

    private fun createDefaultAdminUserIfNotExists() {
        val defaultDevUsername = "admin"
        val defaultDevPass =
            if (productionMode) HashTextGenerator.get(defaultDevUsername, 30, 100, true, true) else "pass"

        if (!userRepository.userWithUsernameExists(defaultDevUsername)) {
            val passwordHashArgon2 = Argon2PasswordHash.get(defaultDevPass!!)
            val userEmail = "admin@flyingdynamite.com"
            val created = userRepository.createUser(
                defaultDevUsername,
                passwordHashArgon2,
                userEmail,
                "Admin",
                "Admin",
                UserRole.ADMIN,
                UserState.ENABLED
            )

            if (!productionMode) {
                println("$TAG -> [createDefaultAdminUserIfNotExists] / defaultDevUsername -> $defaultDevUsername")
                println("$TAG -> [createDefaultAdminUserIfNotExists] / defaultDevPass -> $defaultDevPass")
                println("$TAG -> [createDefaultAdminUserIfNotExists] / created -> $created")
            }

            if (created && productionMode) {
                val sent = emailService.send("Developer admin user created", defaultDevPass, userEmail)
                println("$TAG -> [createDefaultAdminUserIfNotExists] / email sent -> $sent")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun validateCredentials(username: String, password: String): Boolean {
        return try {
            val userProfile = userRepository.getUserProfileByUsername(username)
            val user = userRepository.getUserByTokenId(userProfile.tokenId)

            val state = user.state == UserState.ENABLED.state
            val role = user.role.equals(UserRole.ADMIN.type, false)
            val passwordVerify = Argon2PasswordHash.verify(password!!, user.passwordHash)

            if (!productionMode) {
                println("$TAG -> [validateCredentials] / userProfile -> $userProfile")
                println("$TAG -> [validateCredentials] / user -> $user")
                println("$TAG -> [validateCredentials] / state -> $state / role -> $role / passwordVerify -> $passwordVerify")
            }
            val valid = state && role && passwordVerify
            valid
        } catch (e: UserNotFoundException) {
            println("$TAG -> [validateCredentials.UserNotFoundException] -> ${e.message}")
            if (!productionMode) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            false
        }
    }

}
```

I tried doing this similar way like here - https://github.com/alejandro-du/vaadin-auth-example

Unfortunately this does not work too.
**This is what happens** -> https://wetransfer.com/downloads/43855a41690ff01f3d42114ff337a9e620220406163956/90bbbc

How to fix this ?

Comment: One missing piece could be that you need to store unauthorized access attempts so that the user is redirected back to the "home" view after successfully logging in. See the example here: https://github.com/vaadin-learning-center/spring-secured-vaadin/blob/c7b485d341f29faae28245d475b4402a789d7ce4/src/main/java/org/vaadin/paul/spring/app/security/SecurityConfiguration.java#L40.

Comment: And FYI if you are on Vaadin 23, there are new security helpers that greatly simplify the task of configuring Spring Security in Vaadin projects: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/spring/view-based-access-control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the `ButtonClickListener` in `LoginView.kt` you are **invalidating the session** in the `ui.get().access` expression. The invalidating needs some time and that's why the routing to the home view is displayed a short time until the invalidation is done and the framework is routing back to the login view.

(In addition I would recommend using the `BeforeEnter`- and `BeforeLeaveObserver` interfaces instead of `onAttach` and `onDetach` methods.)